# Formula to divide count if

Tags: excel-2010

Good day,

I have a countif(concatenate)) and another countif(concatenate).  I am looking for a formula that takes the first countif total and the second countif total and dividing the answer of the two.

Help would much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the tag i suggest that you use Excel 2010. Let us assume that you already got the value of `countif(concatenate1)` in a cell called `A1` and the value of `countif(concatenate2)` in a cell called `A2`.

A formula to divide `A1` by `A2` and store the result in `A3` would be:
`=A1/A2` (place this code in cell `A3`).
You might want to look into this, too: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIF-function-e0de10c6-f885-4e71-abb4-1f464816df34

Comment: Is there no way to have the countif(concatenate1) countif(concatenate2) and the division in the same formula?

Comment: Try: `= countif(concatenate1) / countif(concatenate2)`

Comment: I get a #Div/0! error.  Is there a way that I can send you an example of what I want? Please.  I have searched and searched, but can't seem to find the answer.

Comment: This is my formula, but it gave a #Div/0! error.  I have also swopped the count ifs around but it gives the same error.

=COUNTIF(Data!$CQ:$CQ,CONCATENATE('Hit Rate'!$B5,'Hit Rate'!$D$3,'Hit Rate'!$G$1,'Hit Rate'!$D$1))+COUNTIF(Data!$CQ:$CQ,CONCATENATE('Hit Rate'!$B$5,'Hit Rate'!$D$3,'Hit Rate'!$G$1,'Hit Rate'!$E$1))/COUNTIF(Data!$CP:$CP,CONCATENATE('Hit Rate'!$B5,'Hit Rate'!$D$3,'Hit Rate'!$F$1,'Hit Rate'!$D$1))+COUNTIF(Data!$CP:$CP,CONCATENATE('Hit Rate'!$B5,'Hit Rate'!$D$3,'Hit Rate'!$F$1,'Hit Rate'!$E$1))

Comment: It is mathematically not possible to divide by zero. That is your error. It seems that you have to fix your counting in a way that you don't divide by zero. (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_(mathematics)#By_zero)

Comment: Thank you I will look into it. Appreciate it.

Comment: You are welcome. If you need any further information just let me know it. And please consider to mark this answer as accepted. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have taken a look into the formula and it seems that it is more detailed than I thought.  I will need more help if possible.

Comment: If you need help with the implementation of your formula, consider [asking a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: I have Data and that data contains the consultant name, the month the deal was done in, the qualified column (which is Y or N (will mainly work with just Y)), the Business Type (Member or new) and the deal type (Solid, cancelled (Will only work with Solid).  Out of that I want to count the qual Y per consultant per month for New business type.  Then I want to count the number of deals per consultant using solid deal type per month for new business.  Then I want to divide the total of the count for the shows and the total of the deals per month to get a hit rate.  Any suggestions?